# For all square matrices $A$ and $B$ of the same size, it is true that $(A+B)^2 = A^2 + 2AB + B^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, examples-counterexamples

The below statement is a true/false exercise.

Statement:
For all square matrices A and B of the same size, it is true that
$(A + B)2 = A^2 + 2AB + B^2$.

My thought process: Since it is not a proof, I figure I can show by example and come to a valid conclusion based on such example.

My work:

Come up with a square matrix A and B let both be a 2 by 2 matrix(rows and cols must be same).

Matrix $A$:

$A = \begin{array}{ccc}
3 & 5 \\
4 & 6 \\
\end{array} $

Matrix $B$:

$B =  \begin{array}{ccc}
5 & 8 \\
9 & 4 \\
\end{array} $

$A + B =  \begin{array}{ccc}
8 & 13 \\
13 & 10 \\
\end{array}$

$(A + B)^2 =  \begin{array}{ccc}
233 & 234 \\
234 & 264 \\
\end{array}$

$A^2 =  \begin{array}{ccc}
29 & 45 \\
36 & 56 \\
\end{array}$

$(AB) =  \begin{array}{ccc}
60 & 44 \\
74 & 56 \\
\end{array}$

$2(AB) =  \begin{array}{ccc}
120 & 88 \\
234 & 112 \\
\end{array}$

$B^2 =  \begin{array}{ccc}
97 & 72 \\
81 & 88 \\
\end{array}$

$A^2 + 2AB + B^2 =  \begin{array}{ccc}
246 & 205 \\
265 & 256 \\
\end{array}$

Based my above work, the answer is false.

Is there another way to approach the problem? It seems like a lot of work needed to be done for a true/false question which raised my suspicion about whether there is a better way to look at the problem.

Comment: First, since a counterexample is all what you need, you can choose simpler matrices. With a lot of $0$, for instance.

Comment: It is well known that matrix multiplication is not commutative.

Comment: Second, ask yourself: where does the rule $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$ about real numbers come from?

Comment: @alex distrubutive law for addition. But the problem gives it in terms of matrices. I did not even realized there was a rule hidden in the problem until you ask the question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A counterexample is all you need, so you're done. You probably could have picked a simpler counterexample, say with most entries of $A$ and $B$ being $0,$ but yours works just fine.

As an alternative, note that if $A$ and $B$ are square matrices of the same size, then $$(A+B)^2=A(A+B)+B(A+B)=A^2+AB+BA+B^2.$$ From this, it follows that $$(A+B)^2=A^2+2AB+B^2$$ if and only if $AB=BA.$ So, any two square matrices $A,B$ of the same size such that $AB\neq BA$ will yield a counterexample.

Comment: Holy cow! I never thought of it like that. By the way, how did you know right off the bat the distrubitive law of addition will work for square matrices if AB = BA?

Comment: @Nicholas because distributiveness works even when $AB\ne BA$ (it's not related)

Comment: @ratchetfreak Oh okay. I thought there was a relationship to be drawn.

Comment: @Nicholas: It's worth noting that this problem demonstrates that commutativity of multiplication is necessary to conclude that $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2,$ where $a,b\in\Bbb R.$ Distributivity isn't enough, as we see above.

Comment: Would associative prop also be required @CameronBuie?

Comment: @Ahmed: Yes, associativity of addition is required.

Answer (score 14):

$$\begin{align*}
(A+B)^2 &= (A+B)(A+B) \\
 &= AA+AB+BA+BB \\
 &= A^2 + AB+BA+B^2.\end{align*}$$

Is it always true that $AB+BA = 2AB$?

Comment: Of course, you'd probably show the question false by using a counterexample...

Comment: @Arkamis Based on my counterexample, it does not look to be always be true.