# Prove $(A+B)^2 = A^2 +2AB + B^2$ for commutative matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Hello i just need some help with proving that $(A+B)^2 = A^2 +2AB + B^2$ holds for commutative matrices. Maybe by induction ?

Comment: Just multiply out $(A+B)^2=(A+B)(A+B)$...

Comment: See the answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/699505/for-all-square-matrices-a-and-b-of-the-same-size-it-is-true-that-ab2).

Comment: @TheCount  The problem is, the question you link to is about square matrices in general.  This question is about commutative matrices such that $AB = BA$, so that $$(A+B)^2 = A^2 + \underbrace{AB + BA}_{\Large AB = BA} + B^2 = A^2 + 2AB + B^2$$

Comment: @amWhy fair enough. I just thought it would be helpful. but yes, you are right. rescinded.

Answer (score 3):

$$(A+B)^2=(A+B)(A+B)=A^2+AB+BA+B^2$$

If $A$ and $B$ are commutative then $AB=BA$ and

$$(A+B)^2=A^2+2AB+B^2$$

Comment: jesus christ, thank you ...

Comment: @TeodorTodorov: you are welcome!